# yocto and relational database why not?

Tags: database, yocto, relational

I've been working with yocto for a while. The job involves adding a layer on top of meta-yogurt, and thus adding new or modifying existing recipes in this layer. It has been working out so far.

But through struggling with recipes/rules syntax and relationships between them, my gut told me that it would be much easier for the internal implementation of the build system, as well as how the build system interacts with end-developer like me if a relational database had been involved, which defines things, their attributes and their relationships.

But I am no yocto expert (and cannot spend time on it, considering my project schedule) to evaluate a re-design of yocto with a relational DB. Just wonder if this also makes sense to anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as one of the developers who's worked extensively on bitbake whilst I can see why you might think this, it doesn't really make sense for many reasons, not least performance. We once did try using sqlite as a data store backend within bitbake and it was orders of magnitude too slow to be useful compared to our python data store.
The flexibility in the metadata also comes from things like the ability to inject python code and with a database engine, this wouldn't be easily possible.
So in summary, I doubt bitbake or the Yocto Project will ever use relational databases in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to post a comment to Richard Purdie answer from Oct 7 '17 but the comment box didn't allow line break and long text...

I was not aware that there was already a python data store besides yocto objects and rules (mixture of variables, string literals, reg.exp., file types eg. layer, bb, bbappend, conf, inc etc and the "half-explicit", "half-documented" syntax and relationship among them :().

Of course in python environment, it makes most sense to use the combination of its data store and language binding and not another relational db. But I imagine with a relational db, every things such as data store and rules can be implemented in one place, querying/modifying is also an integrated part, binding to different languages / scripting should be possible. Was it actually the same, just the "python way" that I am not familiar with?

When it goes to performance, we already needed a powerful machine (Xeon E5 16G DRAM 1T HDD) to clean build one distro (without fetching sources from remote servers) in an hour and believe other people also use their best available PC for such a serious job as building a distro. So without comparing performance of different db engines and programming languages, which can't be different in great magnitude, I would just forget the performance factor.

Injecting code into a database engine might be difficult. But I guess when using a database engine, just a different programming pattern does the job: the logic of the job is implemented outside the db engine and this process contacts the db engine when needed.

I've been actually not working with yocto for awhile because our yocto build setup actually has been working great and producing new distros for us now and then with the previously prepared layer. Just some thoughts ...